# How to sort strings contianing a hierarchical delimter, giving priority to those at the root level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have a list of strings that represent a hierarchy, where each level of the hierarchy is delimited by a `|`. Here is an example of my array:

```
[
  "fruit",
  "vegetable|lettuce",
  "vegetable|carrot",
  "fruit|apple|fuji",
  "vegetable",
  "fruit|apple",
  "fruit|apple|gala",
  ...
]
```

I want to do an efficient sort such that my output is an array where the strings at the root level come before those with a second level and those come before strings with a third level, etc. Here is what I would like the result to be for the example above:

```
[
  "fruit",
  "vegetable",
  "fruit|apple",
  "vegetable|carrot",
  "vegetable|lettuce",
  "fruit|apple|fuji",
  "fruit|apple|gala",
  ...
]
```

I am trying to do this sort as efficiently as possible (since I have a large list to sort) using JavaScript or AngularJS. Here is what I have so far...but is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks in advance for suggestions.

```
function (a, b) {
  var aLevels = a.match(/|/g).length;
  var bLevels = b.match(/|/g).length;

  if (aLevels == bLevels) {
    return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
  } else {
    return aLevels > bLevels ? 1 : -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this variation:

```
for(var j = 0 ; j < foods.length ; j++) {
  foods[j] = foods[j].split('|').length + foods[j];
}

foods.sort();

for(var j = 0 ; j < foods.length ; j++) {
  foods[j] = foods[j].substr(1);
}
```

`split`ting each item once is faster than doing so for each `sort` comparison, plus browsers are great at optimizing `substr`.

200,000 iterations of this code runs in 0.741s in my Chrome, vs. 1.289s for my original code.

It runs *slower* when I add it as a test case to your JSPerf, but it's the fastest if I include the `food` declaration within each loop:

http://jsperf.com/delimited-sort-test/2

Not 100% sure, but I think in your JSPerf, `food` was being sorted the first time through each loop, so there was nothing to sort for the other iterations.  So it may be best to include the declaration within each loop as I've done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened to the answer that was posted here momentarily, but luckily I saw it before the answerer deleted it (and I closed that browser tab)…

In the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n801xvcd/), the following was suggested:

```
function(a,b) {
  a = a.split('|').length + a;
  b = b.split('|').length + b;

  return a > b ? 1 : -1
}
```

The only issue with this solution is that there is a limit on the number of levels, but I think that will not be a concern for my dataset.

I wrote up a crude [performance test](http://jsperf.com/delimited-sort-test) that shows this method to be superior to my initial attempt.

(Note: I did not indicate in my initial question that the string would also always be pretended with the `|` delimiter, but I did include this in my performance test. So I also tested with `length -1`)

Thank you to the mystery answerer, whoever you were.

Ultimately, my solution (along with case-insensitivity) for now is:

```
foods.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = (a.split('|').length - 1) + a;
  b = (b.split('|').length - 1) + b;
  return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {'sensitivity': 'base'});
});
```

I am open to hearing any faster and more efficient solutions :)

Comment: Ha, that was my post.  I wasn't sure it would be faster than your code, so I deleted it until I had time to do some performance tests.  Glad it helped.